# "Cannot invoke 'insert' with an argument list of type" on a compressed image

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, uiimagejpegrepresentation

Im getting this error and don't know why
'Cannot invoke 'insert' with an argument list of type '(Character, atIndex: Int)''

This code its working:

```
firstImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage,0.75)

restaurante.imagem.insert(pickedImage, atIndex: imagemEscolhida-1)
```

This one is not:

```
firstImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage,0.75)

restaurante.imagem.insert(imageData, atIndex: imagemEscolhida-1)
```

I just need to save to the array the image compressed and i must use "Insert" so i can choose "imagemEscolhida-1" to put the image in the right position... It works with the PickedImage, but once its compressed it doesnt work.

thank you.

Comment: what type is the array `restaurante.imagem` of? `[UIImage]`?!

Comment: Yes.     `static var imagem = [UIImage](count: 5, repeatedValue: UIImage())`

Comment: Well [`UIImageJPEGRepresentation` returns `NSData!`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageJPEGRepresentation), you cannot insert that into an `UIImage` array, no idea why the error message says `Character` though...

Comment: Do you know how can I convert?

Comment: If you want to save the image compressed in the array, you will need to have an array of NSData instead of UIImage and you would need to decompress the image every time you want to display it. This may or may not have an impact on overall performance of your app...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imageData is an NSData object. You need to convert it back to UIImage.

Try this:

```
firstImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage,0.75)!
let compressedImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!

restaurante.imagem.insert(compressedImage, atIndex: imagemEscolhida-1)
```